# Gatsby Build Not Importing Components Or Static Assets but Develop working?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, github-pages, gatsby-image

I am trying to launch my gatsby website off of Github Pages
My build looks great in `gatsby develop`
but something during the `gatsby build` something happens and only a few of my imports actuall return.
Everything else seems to return a 404.

`gatsby develop` and `gatsby serve`:
[image: gatsby develop]

But after I `gatsby build` and click on the index page in `public/` I get this:
[image: index page after gatbsy build]

As you can see my nagivation component and splash image did not render!

I am expecting my `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` to match once I click on the `public/index.html` generated. I am having the same issue when I go to my site after launching it into github pages.

Comment: The networks tab, in chrome inspector tools, might provide some insight.